# change of variable multiple integrals (stewart 15.9)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am learning change of variables in multiple integrals.  We are taking say a region S, and then applying a transformation T to yield a region R.  The methodology that the text uses (intro text) is to take the boundaries of S, and then apply the transformation function to those boundaries to get the boundaries of R.  So say S is a square region, we apply T to the four line equations to get the boundaries/outline of R...my question is why does applying T to the boundaries of S give us the boundaries of R?  Naturally this is convenient, but why does it have to be this way?  The book seems to just assume this.  It is because this is the case for simple transformations and an intro text?  I would have thought you would need to apply T to all of S (not just the boundaries of S) to be 100% sure of the shape of R.

For what it's worth, the section states "Suppose that T is a C-1 transformation whose Jacobian is nonzero and that T maps a region S in the uv-plane onto a region R in the xy-plane.  Suppose that f is continuous on R and that R and S are type 1 or type 2 plane regions.  Suppose also that T is one-to-one, except perhaps on the boundary of S..."